# Visual Recognition IBM Watson python server error

Tags: python-2.7, visual-recognition

I am trying to ibm watsons visual recognition API to select text from an image.
My code works, but 50% of the time I get an undefined server error response from watson. Could this be on my end? Is there anything I should try? Googling the error did not point to any useful information.

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from os import environ
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3
import chrono
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class ProcessImage():
    visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3('2016-05-20', api_key=434jk434k2krandom43kn43n4n24n2342nn')
    def __init__(self):
        print "created ProcessImage object"

    def process_image(self, path):
        with open(join(dirname(__file__), path), 'rb') as image_file:#convert the file (pass the path)
            result=(json.dumps(self.visual_recognition.recognize_text(images_file=image_file), indent=2))
            return result

stack_example=ProcessImage()
print stack_example.process_image(filepath)
```

This code will print out the json returned by the watson api

Here is what returns 50% of the time instead of the correct information:

> {u'images': [{u'image': u'', u'error': {u'error_id': u'server_error',
>   u'description': u'An undefined server error occurr ed.'}}],
>   u'images_processed': 0}

I was thinking about just resending the request if it returns an error... but I am hoping there is a better way to fix it.

Appriciate any help!

Comment: You have a typo at your api key (missing open quote). Also you should not post your API key or others can use it, and you get billed. I would recommend to generate a new key.

Comment: Ahh just saw the random in the middle. I guess you already scrambled it.